How to combine different inputs with different windowing strategies in Apache Beam
So I have a usecase, and need help with what the best approach is. I have 4 different pubsub where I am getting inputs in json. Example:
Input 1: {"username": "abc", input 1 related columns...}
Input 2: {"username": "abc", input 2 related columns...}
Input 3: {"username": "abc", input 3 related columns...}
Input 4: {"username": "abc", input 4 related columns...}

I need to join these and take certain decisions like get some scoring info present in input1, some bytes info in input 2 etc. Input 1, 2 and 3 are coming every 5 minutes per user, and input 4 is event based, meaning if a certain event is performed by user then it will have data or not otherwise. Since it is event based, I need to look back for 13 hours to see if any matches for input 4 but rest are all 5 minutes.
Every 5 minutes, I need to generate a record per user and output some stats from all different inputs and an extra field which says if there was a match with input4. What would be the best way?
I have some code written where in I am creating a Sliding Window of 13 hours which moves every 5 minutes and added an AfterPane trigger, but I am not sure if this will accomplish the task and if there is a better way to do it. Following is the code:
pipeline.apply("Create", inputStream)
                .setCoder(ProtoCoder.of(Input.class))
                .apply("Sliding Window",
                        Window.<Input>into(SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(13)).every(Duration.standardMinutes(5L)))
                                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))                                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(15L)).accumulatingFiredPanes()
                                .withOnTimeBehavior(Window.OnTimeBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY))
                .apply("Convert to KV for User", ParDo.of(... A DofN which would convert it to UserBasedKey...))
                .setCoder(KvCoder.of(ProtoCoder.of(UserBasedKey.class),
                        ProtoCoder.of(Input.class)))
                .apply("Group By User", GroupByKey.create())
                .apply("Derive Data", ParDo.of(new DeriveDoFn()));

Above is the UT code, in actual code I Flatten all 4 PCollections into 1 and then apply the windowing strategy. I wanted the trigger to fire every 5 minutes per User and want to join data, but sometimes the trigger is not firing and the dataflow just staggers.
Thank you for the help.
PS: I used the below Window and trigger earlier, but I am not sure how the trigger firing was being done
flattenedStream.apply("Fixed Window For User Classification",
                Window.<UserInput>into(SlidingWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(13)).every(Duration.standardMinutes(5L))).triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
.plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5L))))).withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(15L)).accumulatingFiredPanes().withOnTimeBehavior(Window.OnTimeBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY))

